# Noncommutative subalgebras in quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let us consider quaternions $\textsf{H}$: noncommutative associative algebra with division over reals $\mathbb R$. It is a 4-D continuum. We know that it has a (commutative) 2-dimensional subalgebra of complex numbers $\mathbb C$. The question is whether $\textsf{H}$ contains a 2-dimensional $\textit{noncommutative}$ subalgebra? Of course, existence of zero and unity is implied here. The key properties under question are 2D and noncommutativity. To put it differently, whether exist a noncommutative extension of the 2-parametric family $\mathbb C$ being a subset of $\textsf{H}$? Examples and references welcome. Perhaps one important point should be added here. The sought-for family must contain, like quaternions, a commutative $\mathbb R$-field.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a quick proof, because I'm lacking the details, although I'm pretty sure they can be filled in, but in general, non-commutativity comes from the ijk elements, the "pure vector" quaternions. And for unit quaternions (we might as well limit ourselves to them), if you have $vw \ne vw$ for $v, w \in \Bbb H_0$, you can rotate $v$ to $i$ and $w$ to lie in the $ij$ plane; at that point, $vw$ has to have a $k$ component. So the algebra that contains $v$ and $w$ isn't $2$-dimensional.

Actually, maybe that **is** a proof:

Suppose you have a 2D subalgebra that's noncommutative. Pick elements $v_0, w_0 $ with $v_0w_0 \ne w_0v_0$. Then neither one is pure-real, since real elements lie in the cetner of the quats. They also span the subalgebra, since they're not multiples of one another (non-commuting guarantees this), hence their span is 2D, hence it's the whole subalgebra.

Let $v_0 = r + v, w_0 = s + w$. Multiplying out, you find that $vw \ne vw$.

So now you have two *pure-vector* quaternions that don't commute. Scale them up to unit length, and you've got two noncommuting vectors in the pure-vector quaternion sphere.

I claim that for any $q$, $q^{-1}vq$ and $q^{-1}wq$ are again unit pure-vector quaternions that don't commute either. That's easy to check.

So pick a $q$ with $v'= q^{-1}vq = i$; then $w' = q^{-1}wq$ must have nonzero $j$ or $k$ component, or else it'd commute with $i$. And multiplying $i$ by $ai + bj + ck$ shows that the product either ($a \ne 0$) has a real component (violating the dimension-2 requirement) or that $a = 0$ and the product is $-cj + bk$. For this to lie in the $v'w'$ plane, it must be a linear combination of $i$ and $bj + ck$, i.e., it must be a multiple of $bj + ck$, hence $b = -c$ and $c = b$ or $b = c$ and $c = -b$. (The multiple has to be $1$ because ... well, compute the lengths.) Both possibilities lead to $b = c = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sound much plausible. I do also feel that 2-dimensionality is incompatible with commutativity. By the way do you know some solid book on quaternions with much details on their structure?

Comment: I learned most of what I know from a section of Steenrod's book on Fiber Bundles, but I can't honestly recommend it. I think that Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes* has an appendix that deals with them in some detail, because they're all tangled up with the Pontriagin classes. I'd surely start there rather than with Steenrod. But also: just play with them for a while, thinking sometimes algebraically, sometimes geometrically (i.e., "conjugation by $q$ turns out to always be angle-preserving"), so that you get a sense of the relation between quat-prod and dot-prod.

Comment: Thank so much for details. I'm trying to read your proof in the context of some different and simplified version of the Frobenius theorem. If we start from an abstract 2-D noncommutative algebra and imply it to have a commutative $\mathbb R$-field (exactly as Frobenius' thrm) then we'll face on a contradiction. The algebra should be empty. Either it is noncommutative or does not contain the $\mathbb R$. That's true? Again, division and zero/unity  are implied.

Comment: I know nothing about general noncommutative algebra; I just happen to know a good deal about quaternions. The other answer, by @rschweib, seems far simpler than mine and uses the obvious fact (from algebra, rather than knowledge of quaternions) that there has to be a copy of $\Bbb R$ in the center of $A$, which completely escaped me.  As you note, though the details of the last sentence of that answer need to be worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be an $\mathbb R$ subalgebra of $\mathbb H$. This means that $A$ contains a copy of $\mathbb R$ in the center of $A$, and this copy accounts for $1$ dimension of the $2$ alotted.

Then let $x\in A$ be something that's not in that copy of $\mathbb R$. We have that $A=\{\alpha+\beta x\mid \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\}$. But clearly multiplication is commutative between elements of this set.

$(\alpha+\beta x)(\gamma+\delta x)=\alpha\gamma+(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)x+\beta\delta x^2$

$(\gamma+\delta x)(\alpha+\beta x)=\gamma\alpha+(\delta\alpha+\gamma\beta)x+\delta\beta x^2$

But these two things are equal because of commutativity of multiplication in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, the last statement is not clear.

Comment: @maximav What about it is not clear?

Comment: Well, from the two formulas in your proof it followed that any 2D-subalgebra in any algebra (over $\mathbb  R$ or over a commutative ring) is a commutative one. Even associativity, availability of division, or zero/unities are not essential? True? So, dimension two has some exclusivity among others.

Comment: @maximav I think that associativity is essential, but division is not, and I don't understand why you would even entertain the idea of omitting "zero/unities."  And yes: the point is that extending by one element into a $2$-dimensional algebra must still be commutative. It is just a simple fact of the thing you extend by already commutes with itself and with the underlying field. Once you hit $3$ dimensions, then all bets are off, because there is no guarantee the two things you extend by commute with each other.

Comment: Ok. I like the explanation: `a simple fact of the thing ... already commutes with itself and with the underlying field'. Thanks. I spoke of unities and zeroes just formally. It's possible that they are needed any way. But this is a different story.

Comment: I realised one point. We used essentialy a property to be a field. If we change the set to an abstract algebra, even over something commutative $\mathbb R$, we can loos commutativity when the algebra has no the unity. So the question on unity was not formal as I mentioned yesterday.

Comment: Shortly, in your notation, let us put element of the sought-for subalgebra $\alpha\cdot x+\beta\cdot y$. If $x$ and $y$ are not commute then 2-dimensionality does not entail commutativity. In this case it seems 
to me that the only necessary condition is, as you put down in your answer, is availability of $\mathbb R$ in center of the total algebra. Thats right? I can not see where associativity would be essential.

Comment: @maximav Perhaps, if you write out all the parens, it does not matter.

Comment: For completion, the condition implying a two dimensional algebra is commutative is that it is unital. There are nonunital, noncommutative algebras of dimension 2.